# Can I PEAR to install packages to a specific folder?

Tags: php, pear

Does PEAR have the ability to install packages to a user-specified folder on demand? I'd like to be able to do something like this to install a new copy of PHPUnit to a project I'm messing around with:

`pear install phpunit TARGET=~/sources/project/test/lib`

Is that sort of operation supported by PEAR? I'd like to use PEAR because of its ability to grab all of the dependencies seamlessly.

Comment: Hope this help -- http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use custom configuration files. As ajreal already wrote, http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php contains instructions how to use custom config files.